# Angular 4+ ordered or generic validation messages

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I use reactive forms validation and I have couple condition per each input field.
I don't want to show all errors at once and I'm looking for a nice way to implement this. Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div class="err-msg"
             *ngIf="stbForm.get('firstName').invalid && (stbForm.get('firstName').dirty || stbForm.get('firstName').touched)">
          <ng-container *ngIf="stbForm.get('firstName').hasError('minlength')">
            Name musg have at least {{stbForm.get('firstName').getError('minlength').requiredLength}} characters
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="stbForm.get('firstName').hasError('maxlength')">
            Name must have at most {{stbForm.get('firstName').getError('maxlength').requiredLength}} characters
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="stbForm.get('firstName').hasError('required') ||
              stbForm.get('firstName').hasError('pattern')">
            This field is required
          </ng-container>
        </div>
```

If I want to achieve this I'd need to add more conditions to those ifs and make it messy. Is there a better and still simple way?

I could make custom directive or even whole component but maybe there's some other way.

I could make one variable per field and set its value from TS but that would require extending builtin validators

Answer (score 0):

if this is only the presentable case you can try to check if the 'firstname' field is empty:

'' == modelForm.value ['image']

```
<div class = "err-msg"
      * ngIf = "stbForm.get ('firstName'). invalid && (stbForm.get ('firstName'). dirty || stbForm.get ('firstName'). touched)">
      <ng-container * ngIf = "''! = stbForm.value ['firstName'] && stbForm.get ('firstName'). hasError ('minlength')">
        Name musg at least {{stbForm.get ('firstName'). GetError ('minlength'). RequiredLength}} characters
      </ Ng Container>
      <ng-container * ngIf = "''! = stbForm.value ['firstName'] && stbForm.get ('firstName'). hasError ('maxlength')">
        Name must have at most {{stbForm.get ('firstName'). GetError ('maxlength'). RequiredLength}} characters
      </ Ng Container>
      <ng-container * ngIf = "'' == stbForm.value ['firstName'] && stbForm.get ('firstName'). hasError ('required') ||
          stbForm.get ( 'firstName'). hasError ( 'pattern') ">
        This field is required
      </ Ng Container>
 </ Div>
```

otherwise you should use a variable but always using controls with * ngIf ... if you think it is too long, the code and the solution, wait for someone else, maybe you will be able to better advise! ;-)

Comment: No, i have more validators than that, approx 4 per each field, mostly required and min/max but some special patterns or emails. I tried your proposition but it does not make it cleaner

Comment: yes, if it was an isolated case it could also "go well" but then I would not know how to help you, I have been working with angular for a few months. I hope someone will give you this information because it could in the future also interest me ;-)